# shifumi : am I on the right path ? (coding js)

Tags: javascript

I'd like to try coding without tutorials so I hope you can help me... So I begin writing the javascript and I am stuck here, Am I in the right path ? I can't display the message, and when I click on the button nothing seems to happen (don't have an error message or anything) maybe it's a syntax issue ? I can't figure it out the issue, thanks

What I want to do :

1. create a function that choose randomly one item from game array
2. create a function when a player click on one button and display a message if the user win or lose...

script.js

```
const game = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

// faire apparaitre aléatoirement le rock paper scissors

const computer = (aiChoice) => {
  aiChoice = (Math.random() * game.length) | 0;
  const result = game[aiChoice];
  console.log(result);
};

// création fonction player
function player(userChoice, aiChoice) {
  document.getElementById("btn").click();
  if (userChoice === "rock" && aiChoice === "rock") {
    alert("Il y a égalité");
  } else alert("ceci est un test");
}
```

index

```
    <h1>Shifumi</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <button id="btn">Pierre</button>
      <button id="btn">Feuille</button>
      <button id="btn">Ciseaux</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Describe the issue. I'm stuck is not an issue

Comment: What is the point of avoiding tutorials (and books and instructional videos etc)? What if you were learning to fly an airplane?

Comment: Your buttons aren't set up to do anything. What do you expect the buttons to do?

Comment: I dont want to follow a tutorial from A to Z, and I try to write on my own but couldnt find a solution with a similar code

Comment: `document.getElementById("btn").click();` clicks the first button. It doesn't handle a click. Also. id should be unique in a document

Comment: Also. Your functions are never called. How do you expect those functions to ever be called? I think you really need to at least learn the fundamentals of programming.

Comment: it's my first project, don't have many experiences, I just see a chapter about js (dom, dom event...) and wanted to see if I could do something after watching a lesson to see if I understand the concept but I dont have anyone to check on my code, thanks for your feedback , I will try to watch again some lessons and try it again

Answer (score -1):

Your first problem is the randomizing. Take a look at the following function:

```js
function getGame(game) {
    return game[parseInt(Math.random() * game.length)];
}

const game = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

console.log(getGame(game));
```

Basically, you get a number between 0 and 1 when you run `Math.random()`. Multiplying it with `game.length` (the number of games) enforces it between the interval of [0, game.length]. Getting the game on this index will return a random game.

Your second problem is comparing the user choice with the randomized choice:

```js
const game = ["rock", "paper", "scrissors"];

// faire apparaitre aléatoirement le rock paper scissors

const getAIChoice = (game) => {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * game.length);
};

for (let btn of document.getElementsByClassName("btn")) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let choice = game.indexOf(this.innerText);
        let aiChoice = getAIChoice(game);
        console.log({player: game[choice], ai: game[aiChoice]});
        if (((aiChoice + 1) % 3) === choice) alert("You win");
        else if (aiChoice === choice) alert("Draw");
        else alert("You lose");
    })
}
```

```html
<h1>Shifumi</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn">rock</button>
      <button class="btn">paper</button>
      <button class="btn">scrissors</button>
    </div>
```

Now, I have changed your `id` attributes to `class` attributes, because using the same `id` for different items in the same document is invalid, since the `id` stands for identifier and having the same identifier to several items defeats the purpose. Then I have added an event handler to each of your buttons which runs a function that takes the inner text of those buttons as value, finds their position in `game` and then compares it to a random computer move. I have logged the results to reflect the situation at hand.